# How to filter MPMediaQuery using comparison predicates?

Tags: objective-c, mpmediaquery

I'd like to fetch all songs in a user's iPod library that are over 30 seconds long. I know I need to add a predicate to the query, but I'm not sure how to do so exactly when it's something more advanced than artist = blah.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
MPMediaPredicate *fPredicate = ???;
[query addFilterPredicate:fPredicate];
```

I also looked at:

```
[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:<#(id)#> forProperty:<#(NSString *)#> comparisonType:<#(MPMediaPredicateComparison)#>]
```

But it seems MPMediaPredicateComparison just has "contains" and "equal to", not "greater than"/"less than"/etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `MPMediaPropertyPredicate` only supports comparison types `EqualTo` and `Contains` as you mentioned. You will need to fetch all songs and loop over them.